# Gnu Screen: How to specify a .screenrc file on startup?

Tags: gnu-screen

Is there a way to launch Screen with a specific .screenrc file, instead of the one in my home directory?

Answer (score 3):

man screen

```
-c file
    override the default configuration file from "$HOME/.screenrc"  to
    file.
```

screen --help

```
-c file       Read configuration file instead of '.screenrc'.
```